# How to easily run git bisect with patches on top cleanly

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I'm trying to run git bisect to find a broken commit, but the problem I have is that the brokenness isn't apparent without an extra series of patches applied on top. I'm just cherry-picking those out of another branch, but the problem I have is that at some steps in the bisect they don't apply cleanly and require some fixup. That shouldn't be a problem, but I can't seem to move on after doing the fixup.

So for example...

```
$ git bisect start
djrscally@valhalla:$ git bisect bad
djrscally@valhalla:$ git bisect good tags/v5.14-rc7
Bisecting: 13382 revisions left to test after this (roughly 14 steps)
[1ea3615b6168eaaf07445c8d32a4c6bc965d9579] iio: accel: sca3000: Use sign_extend32() instead of opencoding sign extension.
djrscally@valhalla:$ git cherry-pick --no-commit 820aca592e0c^..58915847b332
Auto-merging include/acpi/acpi_bus.h
Auto-merging drivers/acpi/scan.c
Auto-merging drivers/i2c/i2c-core-acpi.c
Auto-merging drivers/regulator/Makefile
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in drivers/regulator/Makefile
Auto-merging drivers/regulator/Kconfig
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in drivers/regulator/Kconfig
error: could not apply 6a7e459bf029... regulator: Introduce tps68470-regulator driver
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
```

At this point I need to fix drivers/regulator/Makefile and Kconfig; at which point I expect to be able to carry on, but I can't:

```
djrscally@valhalla:$ git add .
djrscally@valhalla:$ git cherry-pick --continue
error: your local changes would be overwritten by cherry-pick.
hint: commit your changes or stash them to proceed.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
```

Aaaaaaaand I'm not really sure what to do at this point. `git cherry-pick --skip` seems to reset all the changes from the earlier cherry-picked commits. I can drop the `--no-commit`, but I'm not really sure how bisect will handle the fact that I suddenly dropped a ton of commits on top of the point it decided to bisect to.

How should I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first attempt would be, rather than cherry-pick iteratively, just do the whole batch at once:

```
git diff 820aca592e0c^..58915847b332 | git apply -3
```

then fix up the conflicts, it's the last step, add the resolutions and you're ready to test.

This might be a good spot for some manual rerere'ing, you do that by `` mkdir -p `git rev-parse --git-common-dir`/rr-cache `` once to tell git you're using rerere without the automation assists, then `git rerere` when you get the conflict notice, then fix anything that didn't already fix and `git rerere` again after you've added the resolutions.

Comment: Yep this is absolutely perfect; thank you!

Comment: I actually do two worktrees in Git and in one I do bisection on a clean tree and rebasing on the testing tree (which one is actually run on the device).